# adding a new view front of existing view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Have an window based application in mainwindow.xib have an navigationcontroller with table view
so launch of the device get the table view instead like to have a viewcontroller with a button on click table view must be opened

Answer (score 0):

remove the table view from the xib ans put uiview xib . Set the uiview object in xib as the view of rootviewcontroller . Then you can make another tableview controller which will get open on button click in the view.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of `UITableViewController` in `UINavigationController`, have a UIViewController in mainwindow.xib. And on tapping the button in the view of the viewcontroller, show the `UITableViewController` by pushing that.